# Differences in sum of squares between JMP and R when nested effects in the model

Tags: r, model, nested

I'm trying to translate a JMP script into R. In my analyses, I have to perform the following linear model :
`Y ~ G + C + G*C + C%in%L` (equivalent model writing in jmp would be `G+ C + G * C + L[C]`).

I know JMP is giving type 3 SSQ, and I know how to normally get the equivalence in R using proper contrasts. But, I think because I have this nested effect, There is one term that still have a different SSQ in R ans in JMP and I cannot figure out why and how to get the same values.
here is some simulation to illustrate the question :

```
# R code
# library('data.table')
set.seed(18)
TEST=data.table(
 L= c( rep( LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 3 )],3), rep( LETTERS[seq( from = 4, to = 6 )],3),rep( LETTERS[seq( from = 7, to = 9 )],3)),
 G= rep(sort(rep(LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 3 )],3)),3),
 C=sort(rep(LETTERS[seq( from = 10, to = 12)],9)),
 Y= rnorm(27)
 )
 set.seed(18) 
# part add to have the data not orthogonal
TEST_add=data.table(
 L= sort(rep( LETTERS[seq( from = 10, to = 14 )],2)),
G= rep(LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 2 )],5),
C = rep("L",10),
 Y= rnorm(10)
)
TEST=rbind(TEST_add,TEST)
 
 TEST$L = as.factor(TEST$L)
 TEST$G = as.factor(TEST$G)
 TEST$C = as.factor(TEST$C)  
   
model <- lm(Y~ G  +C+ C*G +  C%in% L, data = TEST ,contrasts=list(G="contr.sum",C="contr.sum", L="contr.sum")) 
drop1(model,.~.,test="F",all.cols = FALSE)
```

This will give me this table in R :

```
       Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC F    value Pr(>F)
<none>                24.196   24.285               
G       2    0.2945   24.491   20.733  0.1035 0.9023
C       2    0.4707   24.667   20.998  0.1653 0.8490
G:C     4    5.9115   30.108   24.373  1.0383 0.4163
C:L    11   21.7349   45.931   26.000  1.3882 0.2631
```

But JMP will return this table

```
Source  DF  Sum of Squares
C       2   0.876575
G       2   0.294510
L[C]    11  21.734947
G*C     4   5.911491
```

All fine but for the term "C" : SSQ is 0.877 in JMP and 0.47 in R

I have tried to change the contrasts but the question does not seem to be here.  When I have only fixed effect or simple crossed effect, I have the perfect exact same numbers.
I guess there the nested terme is not taken into account the same way in both program ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague did found me a solution wich I share here in case it can be useful to others.
The R package 'sasLM' allows to have the same values that in JMP ( or SAS).
'''

```
library(sasLM)
aov3(Formula = Y~ G  +C+ C*G +  C/L, Data=TEST, BETA=FALSE, Resid=FALSE)
```

does return

```
    Response : Y
                Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
MODEL           19 30.508 1.60568  1.1281 0.4041
 G               2  0.295 0.14725  0.1035 0.9023
 C               2  0.877 0.43829  0.3079 0.7390
 G:C             4  5.911 1.47787  1.0383 0.4163
 C:L            11 21.735 1.97590  1.3882 0.2631
RESIDUALS       17 24.196 1.42331               
CORRECTED TOTAL 36 54.704
```

Which perfectly match !

still, I dont know why results are differents, and interested in an answer!

Answer (score 3):

Have completely revised this answer in light of you pointing out that sasLM can reproduce SAS Type III sums of squares so that we have a good comparison to use.

Type III sums of squares are usually presented as the difference between the residual sum of squares of the model without the term of interest and the full model; however, SAS Type III works somewhat differently.

Instead of partitioning the model matrix columns into two sets it partitions the model matrix columns into 3 sets:

- X0 are the columns that do not contain the main effect of interest,
- X1 is the columns for the main effect of interest,
- X2 are columns that represent interactions containing that main effect

To get the sum of squares it compares the model consisting of X0 and X2s to the full model where X2s equals the following in terms of X0, X1 and X2.

```
X2s <- X2 %*% t(X2) %*% resid(lm(X2 ~ X0 + X1 + 0, TEST))
```

In terms of the example in the question, suppose we are interested in main effect C sum of squares. First create a model matrix, `X`, without contrasts.  Looking at `colnames(X)` we see that `X0`, `X1` and `X2` are defined by the columns indicated in the code below.  Then define `X2s` and take the difference between the deviance of the model with `X0` and `X2s` and the deviance of the full model.  Note that `deviance` is the residual sum of squares (for a linear model). See [LaMotte (2018)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.00545) for an explanation of the linear algebra behind all these calculations.

```
fo <- Y ~ G + C + C * G + C/L
X <- model.matrix(fo, TEST, contrasts.arg = 
  lapply(TEST[, c("G", "C", "L")], contrasts, contrasts = FALSE))

X0 <- X[, 1:4]  # cols not involving C
X1 <- X[, 5:7]  # C main effect
X2 <- X[, 8:58] # columns containing C other than X1

X2s <- X2 %*% t(X2) %*% resid(lm(X2 ~ X0 + X1 + 0, TEST))
deviance(lm(Y ~ X0 + X2s + 0, TEST)) - deviance(lm(Y ~ X + 0, TEST))
## [1] 0.8765751  <--- same as sasLM sum of squares for C
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer: Indeed, my simulation is not good : it is perfectly orthogonal and so sequential SSQ are equal to marginal SSQ. in this case, ' anova()' gives the same as JMP results. It is not the case if i unbalance data.